# How to use imagemagick from C++ system() call

Tags: visual-c++, windows-xp

I'm using Visual C++ (MFC project) and I need to merge images. I though to use ImageMagick program and call it from my program, so that would do the work.

I downloaded the program of ImageMagick, so if i go to the shell (cmd.exe) and i execute "composite -gravity center view.bmp cointextback.bmp view.bmp" it does the work (composite is an exe inside of the ImageMagick installation, which is in the environment variables).

I tried the same in my project with no success doing the next:
- system("composite -gravity center view.bmp cointextback.bmp view.bmp");
* this gives me an error if i debug "'composite' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file."

- WinExec and ShellExecute with full path of the exec
- Nothing happens. But i don't like this option, because i must specify the instalation path.

I guess to that with system i must use somehow the environment variables, but i really don't know... or if it's possible to do what i'm trying...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution...

In the console is enough typing "composite -gravity center view.bmp cointextback.bmp view.bmp".

In the c++ program i only had to add .exe to the name, and it would be like this "composite.exe -gravity center view.bmp cointextback.bmp view.bmp" and it works...

I hope it helps someone!

Cheers!